# I cannot insmod normal in grup rescue

Tags: boot

I was dual booting windows 10 and Ubuntu when Ubuntu installation done I restart and grup rescue showed up I try to fix the insmod normal it's not working

Comment: You may have only the option to reinstall Ubuntu then perhaps.

Comment: You might have deleted the /boot or if you only had / (root) partition, the root.